# Jquery Mobile: Checkbox function

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm trying to create a function wherein :

where a user checks the check box : the searched items are from myLocal Dbase;
and when the checkbox is unchecked : the searched items are from myNonLocal dbase .

I've been trying to do this but with no lck, any help, suggestions or links that can help me will be great. thank you :)

Comment: Which type of search you have used ajax base or submit your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a "Flip Toggle Switch".
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/switch/

```
<label for="flip-a">Select slider:</label>
<select name="slider" id="flip-a" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

In your search form you should determine the value of, in this case, "slider".

Comment: thank you, but I'm planning to use 1 checkbox where in if user checks it, the search will be for local dbase after user clicks on a button..

Answer (score 0):

Set hidden field using javascript when check/uncheck (1/0) your checkbox then check this hidden value on server side like

```
if(isset($_POST['myhidden_field']) && $_POST['myhidden_field']==1) 
{
    load local db
}
else
{
    load non local db
}
```